# Race condition in httptestserver when changing handler

Tags: http, testing, go, race-condition

I have a slice of tests and I want to run them over one instance of httptest.Server. Each test has its own handler function.

```
func TestAPICaller_RunApiMethod(t *testing.T) {

    server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(nil))
    defer server.Close()

    for _, test := range testData {     
        server.Config.Handler = http.HandlerFunc(test.handler)

        t.Run(test.Name, func(t *testing.T) {
           ... some code which calls server
        }
    })
}
```

This code gives a race when running with "go test -race". It is probably because server runs in goroutine and I'm trying to change a handler concurrently. Am I correct?

If I try alternative code where I create a new server for every test, then no races:

```
func TestAPICaller_RunApiMethod(t *testing.T) {

    for _, test := range testData {     
        server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(test.handler))

        t.Run(test.Name, func(t *testing.T) {
           ... some code which calls server
        }

        server.Close()
    })
}
```

So first question what is the best way to use one server for a slice of tests and change handler on the fly without races? And is it worth it in terms of performance to have one server instead of creating new ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`httptest.Server`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#Server) was not "designed" to change its handler. You may only change its handler if you've created it with [`httptest.NewUnstartedServer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#NewUnstartedServer), and only before you start it with [`Server.Start()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#Server.Start) or [`Server.StartTLS()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#Server.StartTLS).

Just create and start a new server when you want to test a new handler.

If you have really a lot of handlers you want to test this way and  performance is that critical for you, you may create a "multiplexer" handler, and pass that to a single `httptest.Server`. When you're done testing a handler, change the "state" of the multiplexer handler to switch over to the next testable handler.

Let's see an example how it could look like (put all these code into `TestAPICaller_RunApiMethod`):

Let's say we want to test the following handlers:

```
handlersToTest := []http.Handler{
    http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { w.Write([]byte{0}) }),
    http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { w.Write([]byte{1}) }),
    http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { w.Write([]byte{2}) }),
}
```

Here's an example multiplexer handler:

```
handlerIdx := int32(0)
muxHandler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    idx := atomic.LoadInt32(&handlerIdx)
    handlersToTest[idx].ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

Which we use for the test server:

```
server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(muxHandler))
defer server.Close()
```

And code to test all handlers:

```
for i := range handlersToTest {
    atomic.StoreInt32(&handlerIdx, int32(i))
    t.Run(fmt.Sprint("Testing idx", i), func(t *testing.T) {
        res, err := http.Get(server.URL)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        res.Body.Close()

        if len(data) != 1 || data[0] != byte(i) {
            t.Errorf("Expected response %d, got %d", i, data[0])
        }
    })
}
```

One thing to note here: the "state" of the multiplexer handler is the `handlerIdx` variable. Since the multiplexer handler is called from another goroutine, access to this variable must be synchronized (because we're writing to it and the server's goroutine reads it).

Comment: Do you run the race detector? I am on mobile I can't do it myself but to me it seems like a data-race.

Comment: `handlerIdx` is running on another goroutine with the server. But as long as it is only for these tests and the tests does not parel, I think it is ok then.

Comment: @leafbebop You're right. Ran the race detector, didn't find anything, because tests were run sequentially. But you're right, access to `handlerIdx` must be synchronized.

Comment: Thanks for explanation and solution. Its a bit confusing that documentation never mentions its not safe to set Config.Handler directly, even worse that tests run fine without -race flag. I will start a new server for every test.